# Xcode 7.2 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error

I'm programming a QuizApp. I keep getting the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in the line:"`QLabel.text = Levels[LevelNumber].Questions[QNumber].Question`". I don't understand this. I also added and removed the Outlet multiple times.

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit

    struct Question {
        var Question: String
        var Answers: [String]
        var Answer: Int
    }

    struct Level {
        var Questions = [Question]()
    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet var QLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var Buttons: [UIButton]!

        var QNumber = Int()
        var AnswerNumber = Int()
        var Levels = [Level]()
        var LevelNumber = Int()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        func startGame() {
            //Level1
            // Question1
            let Qquestion1 = "What's the name of America's president?"
            let Answers1 = ["Barack Obama", "Donald Duck", "Micky Maus", "Peter Pan"]
            let Question1 = Question(Question: Qquestion1, Answers: Answers1, Answer: 0)

            // Question2
            let Qquestion2 = "How old am I?"
            let Answers2 = ["10 years old.", "20 years old", "5 years old.", "1 year old."]
            let Question2 = Question(Question: Qquestion2, Answers: Answers2, Answer: 2)

            // Question3
            let Qquestion3 = "Who won 2014 the 'Soccer Worlcup'?"
            let Answers3 = ["Austria", "USA", "Mongolia", "Germany"]
            let Question3 = Question(Question: Qquestion3, Answers: Answers3, Answer: 3)

            // Question
            let Qquestion4 = ""
            let Answers4 = ["", "", "", ""]
            let Question4 = Question(Question: Qquestion4, Answers: Answers4, Answer: 1)

            let LevelExample = Level(Questions: [Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4])

            // LevelScience
            // Question5
            let Qquestion5 = ""
            let Answers5 = ["", "", "", ""]
            let Question5 = Question(Question: Qquestion5, Answers: Answers5, Answer: 2)

            // Question6
            let Qquestion6 = ""
            let Answers6 = ["", "", "", ""]
            let Question6 = Question(Question: Qquestion6, Answers: Answers6, Answer: 0)

            // Question7
            let Qquestion7 = ""
            let Answers7 = ["", "", "", ""]
            let Question7 = Question(Question: Qquestion7, Answers: Answers7, Answer: 1)

            // Question8
            let Qquestion8 = ""
            let Answers8 = ["", "", "", ""]
            let Question8 = Question(Question: Qquestion8, Answers: Answers8, Answer: 3)

            let LevelMoviesLiterature = Level(Questions: [Question5, Question6, Question7, Question8])

            Levels = [LevelExample, LevelMoviesLiterature]
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        @IBAction func ExampleLevelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
            exampleCategory()
        }

        func exampleCategory() {
            LevelNumber = 0
            startGame()
            PickQuestion()
        }

        func PickQuestion() {
            if Levels[LevelNumber].Questions.count > 0 {
                QNumber = random() % Levels[LevelNumber].Questions.count
                QLabel.text = Levels[LevelNumber].Questions[QNumber].Question

                AnswerNumber = Levels[LevelNumber].Questions[QNumber].Answer

                for i in 0..<Buttons.count {
Buttons[i].setTitle(Levels[LevelNumber].Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }

                Levels[LevelNumber].Questions.removeAtIndex(QNumber)
            } else {
                NSLog("Done!")
            }
        }
```

Hoping for help!
Thanks N.F.M.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and see what `LevelNumber` is and what `Levels` contains at the time of the error.

Comment: in exampleCategory, you call PickQuestion and then startGame, therefore you are trying to use Levels before you initialize it, or to be more precise, you are trying to access element at index zero while the array contains no elements

Comment: Your level array is set up in `startGame`, but you are calling `PickQuestion()` before `startGame` so your array is empty at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `startGame`, which sets up your `Levels` array **after** you call `PickQuestion`. So you access the element at index 0 when the array is still empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize first:

```
    LevelNumber = 0
    PickQuestion() // call here -> error
    startGame() // init here
```

change to :

```
LevelNumber = 0
startGame() // init here
PickQuestion() // call here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all!!